# Proper intersection modeling

Tags: modeling

How to properly model such triangular intersection?

[image]

What I did is just slapped another rectangle on top of it and beveled it?
But I guess that is not a good practice?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a Cube
2. Extrude its two opposite vertical side
3. Merge the new upper verts to the originals to create a frustum
4. Extrude the frustum's upper side
5. Select all the non horizontal edges and choose Edge>>Subdivide
6. Select the new edgeloop around the frustum and move it to the right position by double hit "G" and move the mouse vertically.
7. Extrude the appropriate faces.
   [image]